# What's the value of this motor snubber capacitor?

Tags: capacitor

A friend of mine has found an old coffee grinder, a SEB 105N I think or SEB 8115 ([example](https://img-19.ccm2.net/Pnj2mgIVhKD5tKb0SbnkxJwg0kw=/ba25954c4f3b4609a6d409d855a14c22/ccm-ugc/imgres.jpg))

I found on [internet (this is the 8115 model)](https://www.toutvendre.pics/moulin-a-cafe-seb-vintage-inox-type-8115_738009109L.jpg) its electrical ratings: 220v - 50/60hz - 170W.

The capacitor in the photo below broke and needs to be replaced but there is no reference. Is it really a capacitor? What can we replace it with?

[image]

The component was fixed at the level of the yellow line

[image]

Comment: Yep. Probably 1 nF, 1 kV rating for EMI suppression. What’s a “compensator” in your title? Autocorrect?

Comment: yes haha ^^ thanks for the information, I'm not used to buying this kind of stuff, I found this site but can you show me which one would fit? I can't find any in 1000v https://www.conrad.com/search?ATT_NUM_ELECTRIC_CAPACITY_any=1%20nF&productType_any=Ceramic%20capacitor&search=capacitor%201nF&searchType=regular

Answer (score 1):

The grinder will work without that capacitor, but it will be a worse source of radio interference. The commutator won't last as long since the resistor-capacitor (RC) circuit, called a snubber, was suppressing not only the interference but also its cause: arcing at the commutator.

So, if this was a situation "away from civilization", then insulating the resistor so it wouldn't short to anything, and ignoring the capacitor, will be OK. If you're anywhere near other people/houses/towns, you do need to fix it before further use though. Radio frequency spectrum is a shared resource and it helps no one if it's being polluted by broken appliances.